# Is consecutive training of the same NN with different loss/cost functions a valid technique?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, multiple-regression, tensorflow

I am training a regression CNN using Python 3.8 and TensorFlow 2+ with a 92 Softmax output.

At first I was using Mean Squared Error as my network's loss function, which was good at predicting large numbers (e.g any value above 0.2) but it was very bad at predicting small values (e.g. 0.04, etc.). To fix this I tried using Mean Squared Logarithmic Error which did indeed fix it but also messed up the predictions of large values.

So my question is: Can I train the CNN using MSLE and then recompile it and train it again using MSE? My logic is that through each training, the loss function would adjust the neurons responsible for large and small values predictions, Is that correct?

For your reference, below is my code, but I do not imagine you will need it to answer the question.

```
BSize = 450
l_r = 8e-4
epchs = 100
drop = 0.1
bn_momentum = 0.8
cost = 'mse'
opt = Adam(learning_rate=l_r)#, amsgrad=True)
# opt = SGD(learning_rate=l_r, momentum=0.89, nesterov=True)
# opt = AdaBound(learning_rate=l_r, amsgrad=True)

start = timeit.default_timer()
model = Sequential()

'''The variable nmbr_of_LAC is from another code '''

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu',
                 input_shape=(nmbr_of_LAC, 1)))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=96, kernel_size=4, activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=2))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=3, strides=2, padding='same'))

model.add(BatchNormalization(momentum=bn_momentum, trainable=False))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(1600, activation='relu', use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(576, activation='relu', use_bias=False))
model.add(Dense(92, activation='softmax', use_bias=False))

model.summary()

# Compiling & Fitting

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss",
                              factor=0.1,
                              patience=4,
                              min_lr=1e-7,
                              min_delta=0.4e-4,
                              verbose=1)

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                               patience=7,
                               restore_best_weights=True,
                               min_delta=0.2e-4,
                               verbose=1)

model.compile(loss=cost, optimizer=opt , metrics=['mse', 'msle'])

model.fit(x=x_train[:], y=y_train[:], validation_data=(x_val,y_val), epochs=epchs,
          batch_size=BSize, verbose=1, callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr])
```

Comment: Irrelevant to your actual question, but a regression loss (MSE) with a softmax output does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: @desertnaut Basically, the NN is predicting the % composition of present materials in an object based on numerical input (hence the softmax, if this helps clarify the context). MSE was suggested to me by an academic professor and it worked decently (compared to MAE and some others). However, I'm not sure which would I use if not MSE. Any suggestions?